# How to use def variable in karate path

Tags: karate

path api/V1/projects/#(projectId)/surveys/#(surveyId)

If i am using above path, it is ignoring everything after first occurrence of #.

Trying to test get and  patch api

Answer (score 0):

Please do this:

```
* path 'api/V1/projects', projectId, 'surveys', surveyId
```

Or:

```
* path 'api/V1/projects/' + projectId + '/surveys/' + surveyId
```

Or:

```
* path `api/V1/projects/${projectId}/surveys/${surveyId}`
```

Take some time to read the documentation. It will save you a lot of time: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path