# How to dynamically build an URL when path is dynamic

Tags: karate

In my first POST call I have stored a variable like lets say 'fruitId'.

In my second GET call I want to build an URL using the above 'fruitId'. Here is my URL:
[https://nice-website.com/v1/orders/{fruitId}/entries?start=2022-11-30&end=2022-12-31](https://nice-website.com/v1/orders/%7BfruitId%7D/entries?start=2022-11-30&end=2022-12-31)

Could you please advice on a solution?

This is what I have tried:

```
Given param start = 2022-11-30
Given param end = 2022-12-31
Given url 'https://nice-website.com/v1/orders/{fruitId}/entries'
 When method get
Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path

Try this:

```
Given url 'https://nice-website.com/v1/orders'
And path fruitId, 'entries'
And param start = '2022-11-30'
And param end = '2022-12-31'
When method get
Then status 200
```

For more ideas, read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883761/143475

Comment: Thank you Peter for your time, your solution helped me :)